# Memory usage of pandas dataframe

Tags: mongodb, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, taskmanager

I am using pandas dataframe for loading dataset from mongodb database. Database collection is having around 2 milion entries and 25 attributes.  When I loaded dataframe with dataset and check the size of dataframe it is almost equal to 1 GB. But when I see memory usage for that process in windows task manager it is equal to almost 8.5 GB. It might be storing some metadata but Why there so much increase in memory usage?(I am using jupyter notebook.)

Following is the code i am using.---->

```
data=pd.DataFrame()    
curs=coll.find({},dic)    
docs=[]   
cnt=0  
normalized_dataframes=[]  
for doc in curs:      
     docs.append(doc)  
    cnt=cnt+1
    if(cnt%50000==0):
        normalized_dataframe = json_normalize(docs)
        normalized_dataframes.append(normalized_dataframe)
        docs=[]
        print(cnt)
curs.close()
normalized_dataframe = json_normalize(docs)
normalized_dataframes.append(normalized_dataframe)
```

Comment: I don't think we can answer this question not being able to see how do you read the data from MongoDB and how do you create a DataFrame - post the corresponding code to your question...

Comment: will the way of creating dataframe help in optimizing the storage?